# Finding items in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am building a eCommerce web application using Laravel and for my products there are three types of filter for example: Color, Style, Industry and these each filter contains some values like this:

```
color => red, green, blue yellow....
Style => Bold,Conservative,Elegant,Floral...
Industry => Agriculture & Farming, Animals & Pet Care,Art & Entertainment...
```

and all products have all three filters so each product have some combination of each filter like **Product_1 =>blue,Floral,Agriculture & Farming**. I am not inserting filters in my product table instead of that I have created a list of all possible combination with an id of each combination so there are like total 4000 combinations of all three types filters so in my product table in just using a column like **filter_ID** which holds the ID of combination.

Now when I am showing products I need to count items available for each filter like Agriculture & Farming [ Total Numbers of product with this filler].

And in that combination list I am not using real filter name instead of that I given an Integer ID to each filter like:

```
Agriculture & Farming = 1, Animals & Pet Care = 2, blue = 3....
```

So now I have three things to counts available products in each filter.

1. Combination list
2. Filter_IDs from Product table
3. Integer ID of each
           Fillter

I tried to count using loops, but its not returning correct value my sample data is large so I can not insert here I am including link to my php file where you can find all data and also what results I need.[Link to php file](https://ufile.io/5m72u)

Code:

```
 // This is all three fillters possible combination in this array 1st level array is a combination 

//And in 2nd level array it conatins 4 items which are: 

//1st item is Combination ID and 
//2nd item is Interger value of actual Fillter (Industry)
//3rd item is Interger value of actual Fillter (Style)
//4th item is Interger value of actual Fillter (color)


// Using this for faster performance
$filltersCombination_integer = [[1,1,14,28],[2,1,14,29],[3,1,14,30],[4,1,14,31],[5,1,14,32],[6,1,14,33],[7,1,14,34],[8,1,14,35],[9,1,14,36],[10,1,14,37],[11,1,14,38],[12,1,14,39],[13,1,14,40],[14,1,14,41],[15,1,14,42],[16,1,14,43],[17,1,14,44],[18,1,14,45],[19,1,14,46],[20,1,15,28],[21,1,15,29],[22,1,15,30],[23,1,15,31],[24,1,15,32],[25,1,15,33],[26,1,15,34],[27,1,15,35],[28,1,15,36],[29,1,15,37],[30,1,15,38],[31,1,15,39],[32,1,15,40],[33,1,15,41],[34,1,15,42],[35,1,15,43],[36,1,15,44],[37,1,15,45],[38,1,15,46],[39,1,16,28],[40,1,16,29],[41,1,16,30],[42,1,16,31],[43,1,16,32],[44,1,16,33],[45,1,16,34],[46,1,16,35],[47,1,16,36],[48,1,16,37],[49,1,16,38],[50,1,16,39],[51,1,16,40],[52,1,16,41],[53,1,16,42],[54,1,16,43],[55,1,16,44],[56,1,16,45],[57,1,16,46],[58,1,17,28],[59,1,17,29],[60,1,17,30],[61,1,17,31],[62,1,17,32],[63,1,17,33],[64,1,17,34],[65,1,17,35],[66,1,17,36],[67,1,17,37],[68,1,17,38],[69,1,17,39],[70,1,17,40],[71,1,17,41],[72,1,17,42],[73,1,17,43],[74,1,17,44],[75,1,17,45],[76,1,17,46],[77,1,18,28],[78,1,18,29],[79,1,18,30],[80,1,18,31],[81,1,18,32],[82,1,18,33],[83,1,18,34],[84,1,18,35],[85,1,18,36],[86,1,18,37],[87,1,18,38],[88,1,18,39],[89,1,18,40],[90,1,18,41],[91,1,18,42],[92,1,18,43],[93,1,18,44],[94,1,18,45],[95,1,18,46],[96,1,19,28],[97,1,19,29],[98,1,19,30],[99,1,19,31],[100,1,19,32],[101,1,19,33],[102,1,19,34],[103,1,19,35],[104,1,19,36],[105,1,19,37],[106,1,19,38],[107,1,19,39],[108,1,19,40],[109,1,19,41],[110,1,19,42],[111,1,19,43],[112,1,19,44],[113,1,19,45],[114,1,19,46],[115,1,20,28],[116,1,20,29],[117,1,20,30],[118,1,20,31],[119,1,20,32],[120,1,20,33],[121,1,20,34],[122,1,20,35],[123,1,20,36],[124,1,20,37],[125,1,20,38],[126,1,20,39],[127,1,20,40],[128,1,20,41],[129,1,20,42],[130,1,20,43],[131,1,20,44],[132,1,20,45],[133,1,20,46],[134,1,21,28],[135,1,21,29],[136,1,21,30],[137,1,21,31],[138,1,21,32],[139,1,21,33],[140,1,21,34],[141,1,21,35],[142,1,21,36],[143,1,21,37],[144,1,21,38],[145,1,21,39],[146,1,21,40],[147,1,21,41],[148,1,21,42],[149,1,21,43],[150,1,21,44],[151,1,21,45],[152,1,21,46],[153,1,22,28],[154,1,22,29],[155,1,22,30],[156,1,22,31],[157,1,22,32],[158,1,22,33],[159,1,22,34],[160,1,22,35],[161,1,22,36],[162,1,22,37],[163,1,22,38],[164,1,22,39],[165,1,22,40],[166,1,22,41],[167,1,22,42],[168,1,22,43],[169,1,22,44],[170,1,22,45],[171,1,22,46],[172,1,23,28],[173,1,23,29],[174,1,23,30],[175,1,23,31],[176,1,23,32],[177,1,23,33],[178,1,23,34],[179,1,23,35],[180,1,23,36],[181,1,23,37],[182,1,23,38],[183,1,23,39],[184,1,23,40],[185,1,23,41],[186,1,23,42],[187,1,23,43],[188,1,23,44],[189,1,23,45],[190,1,23,46],[191,1,24,28],[192,1,24,29],[193,1,24,30],[194,1,24,31],[195,1,24,32],[196,1,24,33],[197,1,24,34],[198,1,24,35],[199,1,24,36],[200,1,24,37],[201,1,24,38],[202,1,24,39],[203,1,24,40],[204,1,24,41],[205,1,24,42],[206,1,24,43],[207,1,24,44],[208,1,24,45],[209,1,24,46],[210,1,25,28],[211,1,25,29],[212,1,25,30],[213,1,25,31],[214,1,25,32],[215,1,25,33],[216,1,25,34],[217,1,25,35],[218,1,25,36],[219,1,25,37],[220,1,25,38],[221,1,25,39],[222,1,25,40],[223,1,25,41],[224,1,25,42],[225,1,25,43],[226,1,25,44],[227,1,25,45],[228,1,25,46],[229,1,26,28],[230,1,26,29],[231,1,26,30],[232,1,26,31],[233,1,26,32],[234,1,26,33],[235,1,26,34],[236,1,26,35],[237,1,26,36],[238,1,26,37],[239,1,26,38],[240,1,26,39],[241,1,26,40],[242,1,26,41],[243,1,26,42],[244,1,26,43],[245,1,26,44],[246,1,26,45],[247,1,26,46],[248,1,27,28],[249,1,27,29],[250,1,27,30],[251,1,27,31],[252,1,27,32],[253,1,27,33],[254,1,27,34],[255,1,27,35],[256,1,27,36],[257,1,27,37],[258,1,27,38],[259,1,27,39],[260,1,27,40],[261,1,27,41],[262,1,27,42],[263,1,27,43],[264,1,27,44],[265,1,27,45],[266,1,27,46],[267,2,14,28],[268,2,14,29],[269,2,14,30],[270,2,14,31],[271,2,14,32],[272,2,14,33],[273,2,14,34],[274,2,14,35],[275,2,14,36],[276,2,14,37],[277,2,14,38],[278,2,14,39],[279,2,14,40],[280,2,14,41],[281,2,14,42],[282,2,14,43],[283,2,14,44],[284,2,14,45],[285,2,14,46],[286,2,15,28],[287,2,15,29],[288,2,15,30],[289,2,15,31],[290,2,15,32],[291,2,15,33],[292,2,15,34],[293,2,15,35],[294,2,15,36],[295,2,15,37],[296,2,15,38],[297,2,15,39],[298,2,15,40],[299,2,15,41],[300,2,15,42],[301,2,15,43],[302,2,15,44],[303,2,15,45],[304,2,15,46],[305,2,16,28],[306,2,16,29],[307,2,16,30],[308,2,16,31],[309,2,16,32],[310,2,16,33],[311,2,16,34],[312,2,16,35],[313,2,16,36],[314,2,16,37],[315,2,16,38],[316,2,16,39],[317,2,16,40],[318,2,16,41],[319,2,16,42],[320,2,16,43],[321,2,16,44],[322,2,16,45],[323,2,16,46],[324,2,17,28],[325,2,17,29],[326,2,17,30],[327,2,17,31],[328,2,17,32],[329,2,17,33],[330,2,17,34],[331,2,17,35],[332,2,17,36],[333,2,17,37],[334,2,17,38],[335,2,17,39],[336,2,17,40],[337,2,17,41],[338,2,17,42],[339,2,17,43],[340,2,17,44],[341,2,17,45],[342,2,17,46],[343,2,18,28],[344,2,18,29],[345,2,18,30],[346,2,18,31],[347,2,18,32],[348,2,18,33],[349,2,18,34],[350,2,18,35],[351,2,18,36],[352,2,18,37],[353,2,18,38],[354,2,18,39],[355,2,18,40],[356,2,18,41],[357,2,18,42],[358,2,18,43],[359,2,18,44],[360,2,18,45],[361,2,18,46],[362,2,19,28],[363,2,19,29],[364,2,19,30],[365,2,19,31],[366,2,19,32],[367,2,19,33],[368,2,19,34],[369,2,19,35],[370,2,19,36],[371,2,19,37],[372,2,19,38],[373,2,19,39],[374,2,19,40],[375,2,19,41],[376,2,19,42],[377,2,19,43],[378,2,19,44],[379,2,19,45],[380,2,19,46],[381,2,20,28],[382,2,20,29],[383,2,20,30],[384,2,20,31],[385,2,20,32],[386,2,20,33],[387,2,20,34],[388,2,20,35],[389,2,20,36],[390,2,20,37],[391,2,20,38],[392,2,20,39],[393,2,20,40],[394,2,20,41],[395,2,20,42],[396,2,20,43],[397,2,20,44],[398,2,20,45],[399,2,20,46],[400,2,21,28],[401,2,21,29],[402,2,21,30],[403,2,21,31],[404,2,21,32],[405,2,21,33],[406,2,21,34],[407,2,21,35],[408,2,21,36],[409,2,21,37],[410,2,21,38],[411,2,21,39],[412,2,21,40],[413,2,21,41],[414,2,21,42],[415,2,21,43],[416,2,21,44],[417,2,21,45],[418,2,21,46],[419,2,22,28],[420,2,22,29],[421,2,22,30],[422,2,22,31],[423,2,22,32],[424,2,22,33],[425,2,22,34],[426,2,22,35],[427,2,22,36],[428,2,22,37],[429,2,22,38],[430,2,22,39],[431,2,22,40],[432,2,22,41],[433,2,22,42],[434,2,22,43],[435,2,22,44],[436,2,22,45],[437,2,22,46],[438,2,23,28],[439,2,23,29],[440,2,23,30],[441,2,23,31],[442,2,23,32],[443,2,23,33],[444,2,23,34],[445,2,23,35],[446,2,23,36],[447,2,23,37],[448,2,23,38],[449,2,23,39],[450,2,23,40],[451,2,23,41],[452,2,23,42],[453,2,23,43],[454,2,23,44],[455,2,23,45],[456,2,23,46],[457,2,24,28],[458,2,24,29],[459,2,24,30],[460,2,24,31],[461,2,24,32],[462,2,24,33],[463,2,24,34],[464,2,24,35],[465,2,24,36],[466,2,24,37],[467,2,24,38],[468,2,24,39],[469,2,24,40],[470,2,24,41],[471,2,24,42],[472,2,24,43],[473,2,24,44],[474,2,24,45],[475,2,24,46],[476,2,25,28],[477,2,25,29],[478,2,25,30],[479,2,25,31],[480,2,25,32],[481,2,25,33],[482,2,25,34],[483,2,25,35],[484,2,25,36],[485,2,25,37],[486,2,25,38],[487,2,25,39],[488,2,25,40],[489,2,25,41],[490,2,25,42],[491,2,25,43],[492,2,25,44],[493,2,25,45],[494,2,25,46],[495,2,26,28],[496,2,26,29],[497,2,26,30],[498,2,26,31],[499,2,26,32],[500,2,26,33],[501,2,26,34],[502,2,26,35],[503,2,26,36],[504,2,26,37],[505,2,26,38],[506,2,26,39],[507,2,26,40],[508,2,26,41],[509,2,26,42],[510,2,26,43],[511,2,26,44],[512,2,26,45],[513,2,26,46],[514,2,27,28],[515,2,27,29],[516,2,27,30],[517,2,27,31],[518,2,27,32],[519,2,27,33],[520,2,27,34],[521,2,27,35],[522,2,27,36],[523,2,27,37],[524,2,27,38],[525,2,27,39],[526,2,27,40],[527,2,27,41],[528,2,27,42],[529,2,27,43],[530,2,27,44],[531,2,27,45],[532,2,27,46],[533,3,14,28],[534,3,14,29],[535,3,14,30],[536,3,14,31],[537,3,14,32],[538,3,14,33],[539,3,14,34],[540,3,14,35],[541,3,14,36],[542,3,14,37],[543,3,14,38],[544,3,14,39],[545,3,14,40],[546,3,14,41],[547,3,14,42],[548,3,14,43],[549,3,14,44],[550,3,14,45],[551,3,14,46],[552,3,15,28],[553,3,15,29],[554,3,15,30],[555,3,15,31],[556,3,15,32],[557,3,15,33],[558,3,15,34],[559,3,15,35],[560,3,15,36],[561,3,15,37],[562,3,15,38],[563,3,15,39],[564,3,15,40],[565,3,15,41],[566,3,15,42],[567,3,15,43],[568,3,15,44],[569,3,15,45],[570,3,15,46],[571,3,16,28],[572,3,16,29],[573,3,16,30],[574,3,16,31],[575,3,16,32],[576,3,16,33],[577,3,16,34],[578,3,16,35],[579,3,16,36],[580,3,16,37],[581,3,16,38],[582,3,16,39],[583,3,16,40],[584,3,16,41],[585,3,16,42],[586,3,16,43],[587,3,16,44],[588,3,16,45],[589,3,16,46],[590,3,17,28],[591,3,17,29],[592,3,17,30],[593,3,17,31],[594,3,17,32],[595,3,17,33],[596,3,17,34],[597,3,17,35],[598,3,17,36],[599,3,17,37],[600,3,17,38],[601,3,17,39],[602,3,17,40],[603,3,17,41],[604,3,17,42],[605,3,17,43],[606,3,17,44],[607,3,17,45],[608,3,17,46],[609,3,18,28],[610,3,18,29],[611,3,18,30],[612,3,18,31],[613,3,18,32],[614,3,18,33],[615,3,18,34],[616,3,18,35],[617,3,18,36],[618,3,18,37],[619,3,18,38],[620,3,18,39],[621,3,18,40],[622,3,18,41],[623,3,18,42],[624,3,18,43],[625,3,18,44],[626,3,18,45],[627,3,18,46],[628,3,19,28],[629,3,19,29],[630,3,19,30],[631,3,19,31],[632,3,19,32],[633,3,19,33],[634,3,19,34],[635,3,19,35],[636,3,19,36],[637,3,19,37],[638,3,19,38],[639,3,19,39],[640,3,19,40],[641,3,19,41],[642,3,19,42],[643,3,19,43],[644,3,19,44],[645,3,19,45],[646,3,19,46],[647,3,20,28],[648,3,20,29],[649,3,20,30],[650,3,20,31],[651,3,20,32],[652,3,20,33],[653,3,20,34],[654,3,20,35],[655,3,20,36],[656,3,20,37],[657,3,20,38],[658,3,20,39],[659,3,20,40],[660,3,20,41],[661,3,20,42],[662,3,20,43],[663,3,20,44],[664,3,20,45],[665,3,20,46],[666,3,21,28],[667,3,21,29],[668,3,21,30],[669,3,21,31],[670,3,21,32],[671,3,21,33],[672,3,21,34],[673,3,21,35],[674,3,21,36],[675,3,21,37],[676,3,21,38],[677,3,21,39],[678,3,21,40],[679,3,21,41],[680,3,21,42],[681,3,21,43],[682,3,21,44],[683,3,21,45],[684,3,21,46],[685,3,22,28],[686,3,22,29],[687,3,22,30],[688,3,22,31],[689,3,22,32],[690,3,22,33],[691,3,22,34],[692,3,22,35],[693,3,22,36],[694,3,22,37],[695,3,22,38],[696,3,22,39],[697,3,22,40],[698,3,22,41],[699,3,22,42],[700,3,22,43],[701,3,22,44],[702,3,22,45],[703,3,22,46],[704,3,23,28],[705,3,23,29],[706,3,23,30],[707,3,23,31],[708,3,23,32],[709,3,23,33],[710,3,23,34],[711,3,23,35],[712,3,23,36],[713,3,23,37],[714,3,23,38],[715,3,23,39],[716,3,23,40],[717,3,23,41],[718,3,23,42],[719,3,23,43],[720,3,23,44],[721,3,23,45],[722,3,23,46],[723,3,24,28],[724,3,24,29],[725,3,24,30],[726,3,24,31],[727,3,24,32],[728,3,24,33],[729,3,24,34],[730,3,24,35],[731,3,24,36],[732,3,24,37],[733,3,24,38],[734,3,24,39],[735,3,24,40],[736,3,24,41],[737,3,24,42],[738,3,24,43],[739,3,24,44],[740,3,24,45],[741,3,24,46],[742,3,25,28],[743,3,25,29],[744,3,25,30],[745,3,25,31],[746,3,25,32],[747,3,25,33],[748,3,25,34],[749,3,25,35],[750,3,25,36],[751,3,25,37],[752,3,25,38],[753,3,25,39],[754,3,25,40],[755,3,25,41],[756,3,25,42],[757,3,25,43],[758,3,25,44],[759,3,25,45],[760,3,25,46],[761,3,26,28],[762,3,26,29],[763,3,26,30],[764,3,26,31],[765,3,26,32],[766,3,26,33],[767,3,26,34],[768,3,26,35],[769,3,26,36],[770,3,26,37],[771,3,26,38],[772,3,26,39],[773,3,26,40],[774,3,26,41],[775,3,26,42],[776,3,26,43],[777,3,26,44],[778,3,26,45],[779,3,26,46],[780,3,27,28],[781,3,27,29],[782,3,27,30],[783,3,27,31],[784,3,27,32],[785,3,27,33],[786,3,27,34],[787,3,27,35],[788,3,27,36],[789,3,27,37],[790,3,27,38],[791,3,27,39],[792,3,27,40],[793,3,27,41],[794,3,27,42],[795,3,27,43],[796,3,27,44],[797,3,27,45],[798,3,27,46],[799,4,14,28],[800,4,14,29],[801,4,14,30],[802,4,14,31],[803,4,14,32],[804,4,14,33],[805,4,14,34],[806,4,14,35],[807,4,14,36],[808,4,14,37],[809,4,14,38],[810,4,14,39],[811,4,14,40],[812,4,14,41],[813,4,14,42],[814,4,14,43],[815,4,14,44],[816,4,14,45],[817,4,14,46],[818,4,15,28],[819,4,15,29],[820,4,15,30],[821,4,15,31],[822,4,15,32],[823,4,15,33],[824,4,15,34],[825,4,15,35],[826,4,15,36],[827,4,15,37],[828,4,15,38],[829,4,15,39],[830,4,15,40],[831,4,15,41],[832,4,15,42],[833,4,15,43],[834,4,15,44],[835,4,15,45],[836,4,15,46],[837,4,16,28],[838,4,16,29],[839,4,16,30],[840,4,16,31],[841,4,16,32],[842,4,16,33],[843,4,16,34],[844,4,16,35],[845,4,16,36],[846,4,16,37],[847,4,16,38],[848,4,16,39],[849,4,16,40],[850,4,16,41],[851,4,16,42],[852,4,16,43],[853,4,16,44],[854,4,16,45],[855,4,16,46],[856,4,17,28],[857,4,17,29],[858,4,17,30],[859,4,17,31],[860,4,17,32],[861,4,17,33],[862,4,17,34],[863,4,17,35],[864,4,17,36],[865,4,17,37],[866,4,17,38],[867,4,17,39],[868,4,17,40],[869,4,17,41],[870,4,17,42],[871,4,17,43],[872,4,17,44],[873,4,17,45],[874,4,17,46],[875,4,18,28],[876,4,18,29],[877,4,18,30],[878,4,18,31],[879,4,18,32],[880,4,18,33],[881,4,18,34],[882,4,18,35],[883,4,18,36],[884,4,18,37],[885,4,18,38],[886,4,18,39],[887,4,18,40],[888,4,18,41],[889,4,18,42],[890,4,18,43],[891,4,18,44],[892,4,18,45],[893,4,18,46],[894,4,19,28],[895,4,19,29],[896,4,19,30],[897,4,19,31],[898,4,19,32],[899,4,19,33],[900,4,19,34],[901,4,19,35],[902,4,19,36],[903,4,19,37],[904,4,19,38],[905,4,19,39],[906,4,19,40],[907,4,19,41],[908,4,19,42],[909,4,19,43],[910,4,19,44],[911,4,19,45],[912,4,19,46],[913,4,20,28],[914,4,20,29],[915,4,20,30],[916,4,20,31],[917,4,20,32],[918,4,20,33],[919,4,20,34],[920,4,20,35],[921,4,20,36],[922,4,20,37],[923,4,20,38],[924,4,20,39],[925,4,20,40],[926,4,20,41],[927,4,20,42],[928,4,20,43],[929,4,20,44],[930,4,20,45],[931,4,20,46],[932,4,21,28],[933,4,21,29],[934,4,21,30],[935,4,21,31],[936,4,21,32],[937,4,21,33],[938,4,21,34],[939,4,21,35],[940,4,21,36],[941,4,21,37],[942,4,21,38],[943,4,21,39],[944,4,21,40],[945,4,21,41],[946,4,21,42],[947,4,21,43],[948,4,21,44],[949,4,21,45],[950,4,21,46],[951,4,22,28],[952,4,22,29],[953,4,22,30],[954,4,22,31],[955,4,22,32],[956,4,22,33],[957,4,22,34],[958,4,22,35],[959,4,22,36],[960,4,22,37],[961,4,22,38],[962,4,22,39],[963,4,22,40],[964,4,22,41],[965,4,22,42],[966,4,22,43],[967,4,22,44],[968,4,22,45],[969,4,22,46],[970,4,23,28],[971,4,23,29],[972,4,23,30],[973,4,23,31],[974,4,23,32],[975,4,23,33],[976,4,23,34],[977,4,23,35],[978,4,23,36],[979,4,23,37],[980,4,23,38],[981,4,23,39],[982,4,23,40],[983,4,23,41],[984,4,23,42],[985,4,23,43],[986,4,23,44],[987,4,23,45],[988,4,23,46],[989,4,24,28],[990,4,24,29],[991,4,24,30]];





 // Available Filter_IDs from Product table

 $items = [17,815,2411,839,400,1200,12,19,1,15,16,18,11,8,9,13,3,274,282,285,273,283,267,275,281,810,814,809,806,807,801,800,533,541,537,594,599,608,535,605,542,606,547,596,598,600,540,548,607,549,534,592,539,601,544,551,546,550,538,536,0,543,1067,1081,1074,1069,1070,1073,1079,1065,1066,1072,1336,1339,1335,1331,1333,1332,1338,1347,1340,1344,1342,1341,1345,1337,1871,1868,1863,1870,1872,1875,1877,1879,1869,1865,1878,2136,2139,2138,2131,2143,2134,2137,2135,2146,2133,2132,2130,2129,2140,2409,2404,2405,2403,2401,2396,2410,2412,2400,2413];



 //Fillter_1 Numeric IDS are 1 To 13
 //Fillter_2 Numeric IDS are 14 To 27
 //Fillter_3 Numeric IDS are 28 To 46
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of approach to solve such tasks is too JS! Some fundamental back-end programming lessons would be helpful in the long run.

For this one I could recommend to re-consider your data model or at least the usage of it. Assuming you're using a proper relational ER-Model, it's better to avoid re-inventing the wheel and just use the [DB query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) provided by the framework and leave the rest ([counting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) etc...) to the existing PHP methods… Eventually no need for any primitive loops or similar complex solutions. So you'll have a convention-friendly code and won't need to attach the whole large file in the future as well!

Good Luck!

Comment: in my previous app version i used inbuilt query builder but it also becomes complex and also performance issues...but this way its executing a lot faster ...please help if you can

Comment: @DharmeshRannga I have no practical experience with Laravel (only with Zend in PHP and Spring boot in Java), but i can't really believe that there would be performance issues in such established frameworks… Perhaps you're doing something wrong. Such way of solving problems is too far from programming conventions and as I wrote above, such sort of filtering and referring with data structures with plain numbers is too primitive and I've seen it only in small local usages in the front-end. So please take your time and find out how you can take a ride on those good wheels out there!